# KendoUI in angular.js - how to update multiple pointers value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I'm trying to use kendo-radialgauge of "`kendo.directives`" with two pointers but my problem is to update the both pointers from controller. 
How can I do it ?

[Two pointers in UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbdFa.png)

```
 <span kendo-radialgauge   k-options="options"   k-ng-model="menuOptions"    ></span>
```

angular.module("app", ["kendo.directives"])

Answer (score 0):

I don't know kendo but I found this:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#widget-update-upon-option-changes 

You can also read about controller-directive communication and about scope.$watch, scope.$on