# How to hide border for Angular-Chart.js - Chart-pie

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I use Angular-Chart.js (the AngularJS Chart.js version) to create a pie. How can I hide the white border ?

```
 <canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-pie"
 chart-data="data" chart-options="options"  chart-colors="colors"     chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride"; chart-labels="labels" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
</canvas>
```

$scope.colors = [
                "#C94C49",
                "#D68550",
                "#EEA638",
                "#A7A737",
                "#85A963",
                "#89AAAF",
                "#39AAAF"];

$scope.data = [12,67,34,9,5,33,71];

[pie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxvEA.png)

Answer (score 5):

Try to reset option segmentShowStroke:false

In regular Chart.js:
var cntx = document.getElementById("yourChartID").getContext("2d"); 
var yourChart = new Chart(cntx).Pie(dataOfChart, {segmentShowStroke: false});

In Angular its enought to assign options in html as you already have:
chart-options="options"

and then if you don't have any other options try: 
$scope.options = { segmentShowStroke : false };

UPDATE:
In newer version segmentShowStroke may not work.
In that case try this:
$scope.options = { elements: { arc: { borderWidth: 0 } } };

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I can't understand what to do with "var yourChart "

Comment: sorry I was thinking about regular chart.js - not Angular one. In Angular you have place to put options in chart-options="..."

Comment: It looks like it depend on version... Try this:{
  elements: {
    arc: {
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  }
}

Comment: Xboomx, can you help me with a question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954898/kendoui-in-angular-js-how-to-update-multiple-pointers-value